# Laravel filter with where statement

Tags: laravel, filter

I have this code in my controller and the output is this

```
$list = ShopDepartment::with('shop','grocery', 'dailylist')->get();
        return $list;
```

Output example for the first item is this

```
{
"id": 2,
"shop_id": 1,
"name": "Grønt",
"order": "2",
"created_at": "2020-10-12 14:03:57",
"updated_at": "2020-10-12 14:03:57",
"shop": {
"id": 1,
"name": "Netto",
"address": null,
"type": null,
"created_at": "2020-10-12 14:04:35",
"updated_at": "2020-10-12 14:04:35"
},
"grocery": [],
"dailylist": []
},
```

But if I want to filter the output for `shop.id` it wont allow me. Any idea how to do this? I assume I can not filter it like that...

```
$list = ShopDepartment::with('shop','grocery', 'dailylist')->where('shop.id', 1)->get();
        return $list;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```php
$list = ShopDepartment::with(['shop' => function($query) {
  $query->where('id', 1);
}, 'grocery', 'dialylist'])->get();
```